# MapFragment ArcGis - The specified child already has a parent

Tags: arcgis-android

I'm trying to display a MapView from ArcGis in Android Studio. I'm using Map Fragments for that, I put in the xml the Map and my other UI stuff. Putting the MapView element in the layout file always crashes, so I'm doing it this way:

```xml
my_main_activity.xml

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/maps_app_activity_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/maps_app_activity_content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
android:id="@+id/maps_app_activity_left_drawer"
style="@style/drawer_listView_style"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@color/esri_gray"
android:dividerHeight="1px" />
```

and this is the framgent layout: map_fragment_layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map_fragment_map_container_frame_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The map configuration -->
<com.esri.android.map.MapView
android:id="@+id/map_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
initExtent = "-9934033.827 1537316.31 -9933312.043 1537940.728" >
<!-- xmin ymin xmax ymax -->
</com.esri.android.map.MapView>
```

My map fragment class holds every configuration of the MapView:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
mMapContainer = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment_layout,container,false);

// Add dynamic layer to MapView (Base)
// Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
MapView mapView = (MapView)mMapContainer.findViewById(R.id.map_layout);
ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer baseMap = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(baseMapURL);
mapView.addLayer(baseMap);
//Creates a dynamic layer using service URL
ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer dynamicLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(dynamicMapURL);
//Adds layer into the 'MapView'
mapView.addLayer(dynamicLayer);

// Set the MapView to allow the user to rotate the map when as part of a pinch gesture.
setMapView(mapView);
mapView.zoomin();

return mMapContainer;
}
```

the function setMapView configures the rest of MapView options:

```
private void setMapView(final MapView mapView) {

mMapView = mapView;
mMapView.setEsriLogoVisible(false);
mMapView.enableWrapAround(true);
mapView.setAllowRotationByPinch(true);

// Creating an inflater
mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// Setting up the layout params for the searchview and searchresult layout
mlayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
mlayoutParams.setMargins(LEFT_MARGIN_SEARCH, TOP_MARGIN_SEARCH,RIGHT_MARGIN_SEARCH, BOTTOM_MARGIN_SEARCH);

// set MapView into the activity layout
mMapContainer.addView(mMapView);

// Displaying the searchbox layout
showSearchBoxLayout();
```

After debuging this error shows up:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{zero.ucamaps/zero.ucamaps.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3936)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3786)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3727)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3700)
    at zero.ucamaps.MapFragment.setMapView(MapFragment.java:313)
    at zero.ucamaps.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:209)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
```

I've tried removing the the MapView from it's parent before returning from `getMapView()`, and that still crashes.

Comment: Could you click 'edit' and check the code formatting? I think that what you've pasted is getting mangled by the Markdown parser - all code needs to have four spaces before it to be recognised properly!

Comment: i tried to add spaces but didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use `mMapContainer.addView(mMapView);` code block. You can say why ? I can answer. When you inflating class you already inflating mapView. With the `mMapContainer.addView(mMapView);` code block. You add mapView two times. So LogCat give error to you.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed this way to show your map:

```
private com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView mMapView;
    ArcGISMap mMap;
    Basemap basemap = new Basemap(tiledLayer);

   com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView mMapView = (com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMap = new ArcGISMap(basemap);
    mMapView.setMap(mMap);
```